# Yocto - how to add blkid.h file to rootfs

Tags: linux, yocto, blkid

I would like to add to some Yocto Linux distribution my own application that includes blkid.h file. In the .manifest file I found `libblkid1` library and `util-linux-blkid` package but in the rootfs I have no such a file. Which package or library I should add to the image to get blkid.h file?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`liblkid1` is a package from `util-linux` recipe (`util-linux-libblkid`). If you want to have the headers, you probably need to add the development package of `util-linux-libblkid`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "util-linux-libblkid-dev"
```

But I don't understand why you need the headers, are you compiling on the target? Because if you use Yocto to compile your application, the header will be on the host side during the image generation, and will not be necessary on the target. Or if you compile with the SDK, you also don't need the headers on the target.